# How to Bind all data to GridView in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have to bind around 25k+ records in GridView. We can do paging but clients don't want any type of paging on the page. They want to show 25+ records in single gird. We are binding but 25K+ records getting too much time to bind. Client again wants to bind 25K+ records in grid and time should also less to bind. Anybody have any solutions over this? Binding grid by simple methods

```
Dataset DSSlipDetails = objclsSlipDetails.GetDataSet();
if (DSSlipDetails != null && DSSlipDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grdGiftMaster.DataSource = DSSlipDetails.Tables[0];
    grdGiftMaster.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You could load data on demand as shown here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: I tried this options also but the client doesn't want on demand. They just want all data to show in gridview in one shot with less time.

Comment: So? Then what is your question. Just bind all the data to the GridView if that is what the client wants. They will come back complaining about a slow page soon enough.

Comment: Then the client should buy  computers with a lot of ram and a very fast network. Same with server

Comment: Create a web service for getting the data and hit it through web browser. Check how much time it will take just to get raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to store all 25K records as a JSON object on the client side from the first request (or via a one-off an API request) and apply paging from that object.

That way you don't go back to the server for more records and the page only shows what you need making the rendering of the page fast.